# Magento 2: cURL webAPI request for Customer search

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Trying to find a way how to integrate Magento 2 via cURL to search for a customer.

For Example the below command is able to bring the customer details of 8

```
curl -X GET "http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/8" 
     -H "Authorization: Bearer myaccesstoken"
```

In the similar fashion how can I construct the search URL with Search Criteria

I spent a day with this [website](http://cyrillschumacher.com/2015/01/02/magento2---search-parameters-for-the-rest-api/) and no luck.

```
curl -X GET http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search 
     -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx" 
     -d '{"searchCriteria":{"filterGroups":[{"filters":[{"field":"email","value":"abcd@gmail.com","condition_type":"eq"}]}]}}'
```

And I got the error

```
{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"searchCriteria"}}
```

There is something wrong in my request...

Comment: http://cyrillschumacher.com/2015/01/02/magento2---search-parameters-for-the-rest-api/

Comment: @B00MER i spent a day with the website and no luck... Update my question with few code snippet now.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you had already posted this link in your question, added an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally after 3 days of struggle got the answer how to put the search criteria in cURL

```
curl -X GET "http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search
    ?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=email
    &searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=abc@gmail.com
    &searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq" 
    -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx" 
    -H "Content-type: application/json" -g
```

The above command will just connect to my store and search for the customer who is having the exact email address.

Answer (score 0):

Try a JSON Request like so:

```
{"url":"/V1/customerAccounts/Search","verb":"PUT","req":{"searchCriteria":{"filterGroups":[{"filters":[{"field":"email","condition_type":"like","value":"%test%"},{"field":"updated_at","condition_type":"gt","value":"2014-04-20"}]}],"current_page":1,"page_size":20}}}
```

...and for further reference:

- https://github.com/choukalos/M2_Api_Example_Scripts

Comment: @BOOMER Sorry, i dont have any clue how to use this JSON along with the curl.  The magento document says GET, but the example shows PUT... Is it possible to put a full URL like the one I asked in my question.

Comment: Updated to one liner